# How to set date by word in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

i have want to ask how to set the date when i enter the name of days,months,year and weekly. This is my example

```
case when description  = 'weekly' 
        then weekly else 
case when description  = 'monthy' 
        then month else 
case when description  = 'year' 
        then year else 
case when description  = 'days' 
        then days else 
        entered 
end &DATE_D
```

Comment: can you explain what is your input and what is the expected output?

Comment: My input is when i put the text 'weekly'.Then the sql for weekly will show the output. thats mean my parameter is text(&DATE_D) for day,month,weekly and year and my output is the  column1              column2              
 -------------------  -------------------- 
 4/4/2012 8:15:42 PM  4/1/2012 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 1):

Yoour case statement doesn't look quite right to me. Are you looking for:

```
case description  
    when 'weekly' then weekly  
    when 'monthy' then month 
    when 'year' then year 
    when 'days' then days 
    else entered 
end DATE_D
```

Comment: My input is when i put the text 'weekly'.Then the sql for weekly will show the output. thats mean my parameter is text(&DATE_D) for day,month,weekly and year and my output is the  column1              column2              
 -------------------  -------------------- 
 4/4/2012 8:15:42 PM  4/1/2012 12:00:00 AM

Comment: This is my sql.i have try many times but the output is error because  Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.      SELECT
    *
FROM
(
   select case description  
    when 'weeks' then entered 
    when 'months' then entered
    when 'year' then entered
    when 'days' then entered
    else entered 
end DATE_D
from customer,lookup_duration_type
  
) as T
WHERE T.DATE_D=&DATE_D

Comment: Try using the convert function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)